# Rancher: Able to do get, but not create objects ( dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: network is unreachable)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, rancher

I have created a cluster using Rancher 2.6.0. Till yesterday everything was fine. But all of a sudden I am not able to create any objects on cluster. However, I am able to query the objects without any issue.
ex: I can get secrets list

```
$ k get secrets
NAME                        TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-j4zfb         kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      24h
imgcred                     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      21h
sh.helm.release.v1.rmq.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      22h
```

But can't create secrets

```
$ k create secret generic splunktoken --from-literal=token=<token>
Error from server: Get "https://[::1]:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/resourcequotas": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: network is unreachable
```

New Rancher, Completely revamped and causing a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by restarting the docker container in all the nodes. Not sure why this problem occured. Even when the required ports are working and configs are in place.